# How can I validate input in python?

Tags: validation, python-3.x, input

I have 3 options that I want a user to choose from (A, B or C)

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
while True:
form = input("Please enter your class:")
if form == ('A', 'B', 'C'):
    print("Please continue.")
    break
else:
    print("Class does not exist, please try again.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if form == ('A', 'B', 'C'):
```

to

```
if form in ('A', 'B', 'C'):
```